# Regex expression does not work

Tags: c#, .net, regex

why does the code below insert an item to the groupCollection even though "aaa" does not contain 12 digits in a row ?

```
var groupCollection = Regex.Match("aaa", "\\d{12}").Groups
```

i'm trying to check if a string contains 12 digits in a row like this:

_def_201208141238_aaaa

Comment: You can check if the regular expression was a match using `Match.Success`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var match=Regex.Match("_def_201208141238_aaaa", "\\d{12}");


if(match.Success)
{
    // string contains 12 digits in a row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Match` method always need to return something. And it returns match object with `success`  value `false`. I guess you want to use `Matches` and get the `MatchCollection`. In this case you should get 0 matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
            // Option 1
            // If you are sure there could be only one match then you can check this boolean flag.
            var isSuccess = Regex.IsMatch("aaa", "\\d{12}");

            // Option 2
            // There could be multiple matches.
            var matchCollection = Regex.Matches("aaa", "\\d{12}");

            foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
            {
                // Process your code for each match
            }
```